# Is it a bad idea to use IDisposable as a coding standard

Tags: coding-style, idisposable

I enjoy the "using" construct.  I like how all variables defined within it go out of scope when you exit.  I like it from a styling perspective.  It tells me when looking at code that it's using this object and now it's done with it.  I know at a glance that this object is not used anywhere else in the code.  It wraps everything in a neat package.  I like how it automatically calls dispose for me.

Given these niceties, I'm considering using IDisposable on every single class I write even if it has no resources to manage.  This feels completely wrong to me, but I'm failing to come up with concrete reasons why I should not do this.  Is there incurred overhead on using IDisposable when it's not necessary?  Are there other things that I'm not thinking through here?

In a nutshell, my question is what drawbacks are there in implementing IDisposable when it's not needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class or interface should only implement `IDisposable` if and only if it methods which request the creation of a new instance should assume the responsibility for ensuring that the instance does not get abandoned without `Dispose` being called first.  Note that this condition may apply even if a type has no cleanup responsibilities *if* factory methods which use that type for its return value may sometimes create things that do have cleanup responsibilities.  For example, even though 99% of `IEnumerator<T>` implementations don't have anything requiring cleanup, `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable` because code which calls `GetEnumerator()` on arbitrary implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` will sometimes receive `IEnumerator<T>` implementations that do require cleanup.  It is easier for code which calls `GetEnumerator()` to unconditionally ensure that its `Dispose` method gets invoked, than it would be for the code to determine whether `Dispose` is necessary.

There is nothing wrong with employing `IDisposable` objects in conjunction with `using` to create scoped behaviors, but types should only implement `IDisposable` in cases where it would serve some useful purpose.  One should not employ `using` with types whose `Dispose` method is intended not to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

#### Don't do that.

Implementing `IDisposable` tells people who see the class that it has something to clean up.

What you want is ordinary variable scope; just use normal scope blocks:

```
{
    int x;
    ...
}
// Cannot use x
```

Comment: Couldn't have put it more succinctly, +1.

Answer (score 0):

.Net code in general is managed code. Memory management is handled for us.

Implementing the IDisposable interface indicates that there are resources that we have to manage, for example database connections or files streams.